# Is Loading Bitmaps for static use bad for Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, garbage-collection

I have created a class that loads Bitmap images and stores them in a static context:

```
public class ImgLoader extends View {

public static Bitmap tree1;

public ImgLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    loadImgs();
}

public void loadImgs() {
    tree1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tree);
}
}
```

I then later access this image by doing this:

```
Bitmap tree = ImgLoader.tree1;
```

Are there any alternatives to doing something like this? Because it may cause some issues with the GC.

Comment: Load the image when it is required. Don't keep it in memory unnecessarily .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this method to you class

```
public void recycleBitmap(){
    if(tree1 != null){
        tree1.recycle();
    }
    tree1 = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Loading bitmap in static way is bad for garbage collection. Since bitmap will remain in memory, it will consume the memory and will not be garbage collected. However there are few benefits.

This is a better way to display images. If you are using same image multiple times, making it static and reusing will surely save some memory. Also If you want to display image on multiple views and do not want to load them, making it static will help you. As we know, inflating UI is a heavy operation so as the loading bitmap from IO. Thus static images are good to use especially if there are several copies needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SoftReference` to store your reference to the image. Then if no-where in your program is using the image the garbage collector is free to clean it up.

You will need to reload the image if it has been garbage collected but otherwise it will stay in memory ready to be re-used.